# How to call Github repo using Azure DevOps pipeline?

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

How can I call the github repo using Azure pipeline, in that case to build the code (Pom File).

My lead said that, I don't need to clone or import the code, instead I need to call the github repo/code using the Azure yaml template that we're using to build it using Maven.

Do I really need a github service connection in Azure for it? or do I need to add a task like a script to call the github repo?

Any inputs is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Cloning and importing the code from github is not an option.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "call the github repo"? you can checkout the repo in your azure pipeline if that's what you're asking

Comment: Did you look at the Azure Pipelines documentation? Or follow up with the person who told you what to do and ask for an explanation or assistance?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the DevOps pipeline, it will ask you to choose the source code, you can specify the github, and it will redirect to authorization page, after it's done, the service conneciton to github will be `automatically` created if you don't have before.

[image]

You can follow the official doc [Create your first pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser) for the details.

[image]

In yaml pipeline, **the current repository(github in this case) will checked out to the agent machine by default**, you don't need to add task/script to pull the code. If you need to check out other repo, please check doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops).

Just make sure you have stored build files(POM file..etc) on github repo.  Then in the yaml content, you can add maven task or command line, sample:

```
steps:
- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    goals: 'package'
```

Comment: @NippyBear, may i know if the reply helps? If it is, would you help to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so it can help others as well? Or please let me know if you still have any queries, thanks.